# Autodesk Platform Services iPad & iPhone issues

Tags: ios, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using an Autodesk Platform Services website on Windows and Android with no problem.

When I open the site in iPad or iPhone, the site crashes and the page reloads every time I change models in AggregatedView.

Also the button for the Autodesk.BoxSelection extension dosen't show up. I use the code bellow to force the button to show.

```
    agViewer.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT, event => {
        if (event.extensionId === 'Autodesk.BoxSelection') {
                let ext = agViewer.viewer.getExtension(event.extensionId);
                ext.addToolbarButton(true);
        }
    });
```

Both two issues don't occur in Android devices.

Any clue how to solve those two iOS specific issues?

Comment: Found that Autodesk.BoxSelection is not loaded on iOS mobile devices at startup

Comment: Also found that's a specs problem on the devices tested. Tested on a more powerfull iPad and all when well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that:

- Autodesk.BoxSelection is not loaded on iOS mobile devices at startup
- The reset was a specs problem on the devices tested. Tested on a more powerfull and recent iPad and all when well.